# Duda con opencart

Tags: opencart, cart, sessionid

I'm developing a TPV App for OpenCart to my final project of my advanced cycle called Administration of network systems.

Going into the study of the database and when programming, I have problems with the CART table. It is necessary column sesion_id in order to see what the client is adding to the cart. How can I get that value to add it to my final project?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is an English resource, so please rewrite your question in English.

Comment: Ok sorry Eduard!
I'm developing a TPV App for OpenCart to my final project of my advanced cycle called Administration of network systems.
Going into the study of the database and when programming, I have problems with the CART table. It is necessary column sesion_id in order to see what the client is adding to the cart.
How can I get that value to add it to my final project?

Comment: Hi, please edit your original post and write it in English. I'm not familiar with opencart, so I have no answer for you, but hopefully someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to reach the '`$this->cart`' variable from anywhere this library (https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/cart/cart.php) contains all you need most of the time. If you want to create your own queries you are able to reach the session id through '`$this->session->getId()`'.